# What does the * mean next to a filename in the ouput of the command ll?

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I have a doubt related the output of **ll** command.

When, in my shell, I execute the **ll** command I obtain this output:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 andrea andrea 104215 ott 15 15:56 atmosfs*
```

Why I have the * next to the file name **atmosfs**? What does it means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` means that the file is executable. `ls -Fl` will show `*` for executable files and `/` this is useful when the output is monochrome.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the command `ll` is not a command but an alias for 'ls -alF'.

This is the default on some distributions (e.g. Ubuntu 12.04).

The actual command used is thus `ls` and `info ls` shows the following:

```
`-F'
`--classify'
`--indicator-style=classify'
     Append a character to each file name indicating the file type.
     Also, for regular files that are executable, append `*'.  The file
     type indicators are `/' for directories, `@' for symbolic links,
     `|' for FIFOs, `=' for sockets, `>' for doors, and nothing for
     regular files.
```

Specifically, the **for regular files that are executable, append `*`.**